# MySQL dump from java with where condition on multiple table (Or) Multiple command line

Tags: java, mysql

```
String executeCmd1 = "";
            String executeCmd2 = "";                
            
            executeCmd1 = "C:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.14/bin/mysqldump -u "+dbUser+" -p"+dbPass+" "+dbName+" "+dbTable+" --where=id="+whereStatement+" --single-transaction --skip-lock-tables --no-create-info -r D:/backup.sql";
            executeCmd2 = "C:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.14/bin/mysqldump -u "+dbUser+" -p"+dbPass+" "+dbName+" "+dbTable_1+" --where=course_id="+whereStatement+" --single-transaction --skip-lock-tables --no-create-info >> D:/backup.sql";
            System.out.println(executeCmd1);
            System.out.println(executeCmd2);
            Process runtimeProcess =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd1);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
            if(processComplete == 0){

            System.out.println("Backup taken successfully");
            Process runtimeProcess1 =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd2);
            int processComplete1 = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

            } else {

                System.out.println("Could not take mysql backup");

            }
```

while running the application first command line executes and backup is saved in file. Then running the second command but it's not working.

Comment: Is the condition `whereStatement` the same for both tables?  That is, both `id` and `course_id` are supposed to have the same value?  Did you try saving the results of the second query into another file?

Comment: Most probably the reason the second one doesn't work is it involves a *shell* redirect. You haven't got a shell. So you need to execute mysqldump via cmd.exe. I strongly advise you to use `ProcessBuilder`. Your coding will be a lot easier, be more flexible and be more readable

Comment: Yes the where statement same for both tables the id and course_id will have the same value, and table-1( id) is the foreign key value for table-2(course_id). No, I am trying to save the second command line result in the same file where I kept the first command line result: @NowhereMan

Answer (score 1):

You could do this sort of thing with `ProcessBuilder`:

```
public class Dump {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // (NB: All variables previously declared)
            String[] executeCmd2 = {
                "cmd.exe",
                "/c",
                "C:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.14/bin/mysqldump",
                "-u",
                dbUser,
                "-p",
                dbPass,
                dbName,
                dbTable_1,
                "--where=course_id=",
                whereStatement,
                "--single-transaction",
                "--skip-lock-tables",
                "--no-create-info",
                ">> D:/backup.sql"
            };
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(executeCmd2);
            pb.inheritIO();
            pb.start();

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```